# CSS, HTML Scrollable Div using the window Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to have a scrollable div in a page where all the other contents are fixed but that div is scrollable by the window scrollbar instead of it's own scroll?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without JavaScript? What if the window doesn't have a scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the dimensions of the fixed content are, i.e. the offset from the edges of the window to the edges of the scrolling content, then really all you need to do is put margins on the scrolling content. Then the fixed content is displayed in the margins, as it were.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000
}
header {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 3;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FBB
}
nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 3em;
  bottom: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 7em;
  background: #BBF
}
aside {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 3em;
  bottom: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 7em;
  background: #BFF
}
main {
  display: block;
  margin: 3em 9em 3em 9em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #FFB
}
footer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 3;
  width: 100%;
  background: #BFB
}
```

```html
<header>This is the fixed header</header>
<nav>And the fixed nav bar.<br />
  <a href="#">Go to top</a><br />
  <a href="#bottom">Go to bottom</a>
</nav>
<aside>And the fixed sidebar.
  <br />With some content.</aside>
<main>This is the scrolling content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  <br />Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
  sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt
  ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit
  esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  <br />At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
  animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda
  est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
  voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.<span id="bottom"></span>
</main>
<footer>And the fixed footer</footer>
```

I gave everything different colours to make it clear what the trick is, but you can give all the fixed containers the same background colour, naturally.